# What is the difference between Mass Effect 3 and Mass Effect 3 EN only?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I recently bought the Mass Effect trilogy and when I redeemed it to my Origin Account, Mass Effect 3 appeared twice. In normal version and an EN Only version. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the name, the EN only version only supports the English language.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the difference is that one is the extended ending version (EN) and one is the original release version